# MySQL getting last month instead of specific week

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date, datetime

I have this part of my SQL-statement where I select the one week depending on the input date:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(md.`mydate`, '%d.%m.%Y'),
...
DAYNAME(md.`mydate`) FROM `mydates` md
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM `import` 
    WHERE `Zeitspanne` != 'Anwesenheit' 
    AND `Person` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($expName)."') g 
    ON (md.`mydate` =  STR_TO_DATE(g.`Datum`, '%d.%m.%Y') )
WHERE WEEK(md.`mydate`,1) = WEEK('".$getStart[2].$d.$getStart[1].$d.$getStart[0]."',1)
AND YEAR(md.`mydate`) = YEAR('".$getStart[2].$d.$getStart[1].$d.$getStart[0]."')";
```

Now I want to select the last month (in this case September) instead of the user-specific week like this:

```
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT * FROM `import` 
    WHERE `Zeitspanne` != 'Anwesenheit' 
    AND `Person` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($expName)."') g 
    ON (md.`mydate` =  STR_TO_DATE(g.`Datum`, '%d.%m.%Y') )
WHERE MONTH(md.`mydate`,1) = MONTH('".$getStart[2].$d.$getStart[1].$d.$getStart[0]."' - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) 
AND YEAR(md.`mydate`) = YEAR('".$getStart[2].$d.$getStart[1].$d.$getStart[0]."' - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)";
```

...but it seems not to work.

Comment: can you post some data for us to understand what you want

Comment: For better understandig, I have this fiddle which selects different data of the staff for one week. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/130d8e/1

Comment: so whats the issue? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/130d8e/25

Comment: That's it. Thank you. I forgot that MONTH() has no paramenter 1 or something like this. Too much work today.

Comment: oh ok i'll post an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the issue is you are passing an additional parameter to MONTH()
I also don't think you need to do an interval on the YEAR (but you may want to not sure)

change `WHERE MONTH(md.mydate,1)` to `WHERE MONTH(md.mydate)`